# Show two continuous, bounded functions with multiple independant random variables as parameters are independant

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $m < n$. Let $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ independant random variables and $f : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^{n−m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded continuous functions. Show $Y_1 := f(X_1, . . . , X_m)$ and
$Y_2 := g(X_{m+1}, . . . , X_n)$ independant random variables.

At least I already showed that f,g are indeed random variables.

Further I tried interpreting the functions on the product space $\mathbb{R}^m\mathbin\otimes\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, but this way I lose the comparability between the $X_i$. I am familiar with the alternative definition for independency: $$\int_{\Omega} g_1(Y_1)g_2(Y_2) d\mathbb{P} = \int_{\Omega} g_1(Y_1)d\mathbb{P}\int_{\Omega} g_2(Y_2) d\mathbb{P}$$
for $g_1,g_2$ measurable and absolutely integrable.

Can one give me a hint what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your alternative definition of independency is wrong : the equality $\mathbb E[Y_1Y_2] = \mathbb E[Y_1] \mathbb E[Y_2] $ does not imply independence but only uncorrelatedness. Take a look at [the counterexamples on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelatedness_(probability_theory)#Examples_of_dependence_without_correlation) to see that it is not equivalent to independence.

To prove independence, you need to show that for any sets $A_1\subseteq \mathbb R^m$ and $A_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^{n-m} $, $$\mathbb P(Y_1\in A_1 \cap Y_2\in A_2) =  \mathbb P(Y_1\in A_1)\mathbb P(Y_2\in A_2). \tag1$$

Now, to prove $(1)$, notice that the event $\{Y_1\in A_1 \cap Y_2\in A_2\}$ can be rewritten as :
$$\begin{align}\{Y_1\in A_1 \cap Y_2\in A_2\} &=\left\{\omega \in \Omega : f(X_1(\omega), \ldots , X_m(\omega)) \in A_1 \cap g(X_{m+1}(\omega), \ldots , X_n(\omega))\in A_2\right\} \\
&=\left\{\omega \in \Omega : (X_1(\omega), \ldots , X_m(\omega)) \in f^{-1}(A_1) \cap (X_{m+1}(\omega), \ldots , X_n(\omega))\in g^{-1}(A_2)\right\} \\ \end{align} $$

And conclude by independence of $(X_1, \ldots , X_m)$ and $(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)$.

Comment: many thanks for your answer! maybe i did not make the alternative definition clear enough. For $Y_1,Y_2$ to be independent the equality $\mathbb{E}[g_1(Y_1)g_2(Y_2)]= \mathbb{E}[g_1(Y_1)]\mathbb{E}[g_2(Y_2)]$ must hold for every $g_1,g_2$ measureable and absolutely integrable. uncorrelatedness is true for $g_1 = g_2 = 1$ you are right.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I read your post too fast ! If you want to prove it with your definition then for any $g_1$ $g_2$ bounded measurable, you have $g_1\circ f$ and $g_2\circ g$ bounded measurable too (assuming we're dealing with the right measures) and so you can conclude by independence of the two random vectors $(X_1, \ldots , X_m)$ and $(X_{m+1}, \ldots , X_n)$

Comment: further more i guess you meant $A_1,A_2 \subseteq\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I made a mistake. The proof is the same though